# Return DataType for Byte[] in AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a controller which return a byte[] as follows:

```
     public JsonResult GeneratePDF(string orderQuoteId)
    { 
          byte[] pdfData = ServiceCall(); 
          return Json(pdfData);
    }
```

The ajax call is as follows but it fails:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GeneratePDF", "AccountDetail")',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',            
            data: { 'orderQuoteId': orderQuoteId },
            success: function (result) {
             alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured while creating PDF');
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you post the AJAX error and/or any server stack trace from the C# code?

Comment: you are setting ajax call to do get while you are posting parameter in body

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  yes I want to send a parameter and then grab the result from the call. I think its allowed. I saw several examples doing this.

Comment: @Yserbius While debugging I checked that the controller returns a byte array.But the client side debugging does not give any error and directly prompts the failure alert!

Comment: try like: `return Json(new { result = pdfData},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`